# Do Macbooks with protective cases fit into the BookArc Desktop Stand?

Tags: macbook-pro, case

I have a 15" Macbook Pro in a [Speck](http://www.speckproducts.com/macbook-cases/seethru-satin-macbook-pro-case-15-black.html) protective case.

Will this fit into a [Twelve South BookArc Desktop Stand for Notebooks](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TW852?mco=MjI4ODAxMzA) comfortably? The protective case adds a little to the body of the Macbook, my concern is that it won't fit.

[image: Speck case for Macbook]

[image: Twelve South BookArc Desktop Stand for Notebooks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works great with the Speck case, just go up an insert size and you're good. Check this out for some pictures of a similar setup: http://www.runaroundtech.com/2011/03/25/review-bookarc/